# Issue using pspice .lib in ltspice - Unknown Parameter

Tags: ltspice, texas-instruments, pspice, modeling

I received an unencrypted PSpice model of a TI Boost Converter (TPS43061) and I am trying to use it in LTSpice but I'm getting the following error and I'm not sure what I can do about it.

> Unknown parameter: "_u7"
>   in line:
>   "b:u1:§e_u7 u1:pwmok 0≪:0≫ v=limit(v(u1:n34828,u1:n35569)*1e6,0,1)
>   _u7 n34828 n35569 1g"

Here is the Spice Code:

```
*$
* TPS43061
*****************************************************************************
* (C) Copyright 2012 Texas Instruments Incorporated. All rights reserved. 
* TI Information – Selective Disclosure to Busek                                           
*****************************************************************************
** This model is designed as an aid for customers of Texas Instruments.
** TI and its licensors and suppliers make no warranties, either expressed
** or implied, with respect to this model, including the warranties of 
** merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.  The model is
** provided solely on an "as is" basis.  The entire risk as to its quality
** and performance is with the customer
*****************************************************************************
*
* This model is subject to change without notice. Texas Instruments
* Incorporated is not responsible for updating this model.
*
*****************************************************************************
*
** Released by: WEBENCH Design Center, Texas Instruments Inc.
* Part: TPS43061
* Date: 16NOV2012
* Model Type: TRANSIENT
* Simulator: PSPICE
* Simulator Version: 16.2.0.p001
* EVM Order Number: TPS43061EVM-198
* EVM Users Guide: SLVU799–November 2012
* Datasheet: 
*
* Model Version: Final 1.00
*
*****************************************************************************
*
* Updates:
*
* Final 1.00
* Release to Web.
*
*****************************************************************************
.SUBCKT TPS43061_TRANS AGND BOOT COMP EN FB HDRV ISNSN ISNSP LDRV PGND PGOOD
+  PWPD RT_CLK SS SW VCC VIN  
E_ABM16         OVP 0 VALUE { IF(V(FB)>1.322,1,0)    }
R_R11         N221992 N222430 R_R11 10k TC=0,0 
.model        R_R11 RES R=1 DEV=15%
X_U35         N86008 PWMOK N87095 OVP N233062 NOR4_BASIC1V
C_COSC         0 RMP  9.043p  TC=0,0 
V_V13         N662486 0 1
X_U12         N74211 EN d_d1 PARAMS:
X_U9         CLK_SYNC N16800609 AND_OUT AND2_BASIC_GEN PARAMS: VDD=1 VSS=0
+  VTHRESH=500E-3
X_U13         N74211 N70705 d_d1 PARAMS:
E_ABM1         VREFI 0 VALUE { IF(V(SS)<1.22,V(SS),1.23)    }
G_GEA1         VIN 0 ENI 0 500u
X_U30         N169627 LSOFF INV_BASIC1V
I_I1         0 SS DC 6u  
C_CSYNC1         0 N221992  1p  TC=0,0 
C_CSYNC         0 SYNC  4p  TC=0,0 
E_DIFF4         N40278 0 VALUE {V(ISNSP,ISNSN)}
G_GSNSP         ISNSP 0 ENI 0 45u
E_U7         PWMOK 0 VALUE {LIMIT(V(N34828,N35569)*1E6,0,1)} _U7 N34828 N35569
+  1G

X_U47         LDRV VCC d_d1 PARAMS:
E_ABM14         N140118 0 VALUE { IF(V(ENI)>0.5,2.125,3.3)    }
V_V9         N38710 0 3.75m
R_R12         N241555 RT_CLK R_R12 75k TC=0,0 
.model        R_R12 RES R=1 DEV=15%
X_S10    SYNCI 0 N343790 SLP TPS43061_TOPLEVEL_S10 
X_U6         N29782 CLK BUF_DELAY_BASIC1V PARAMS: DELAY=10N
X_U39         N283683 N247956 N320210 AND2_BASIC1V
E_U5         N22414 0 VALUE {LIMIT(V(N24138,RMP)*1E6,0,1)} _U5 N24138 RMP 1G

R_R15         N324370 MXDC_SYNC R_R15 1000k TC=0,0 
.model        R_R15 RES R=1 DEV=15%
R_R14         N309663 MXDC_SYNC R_R14 2.5k TC=0,0 
.model        R_R14 RES R=1 DEV=15%
C_COEA         0 COMP  20p  TC=0,0 
X_U58         SYNCI SYNCI_INV INV_BASIC1V
R_R7         PGND 0 R_R7 1m TC=0,0 
.model        R_R7 RES R=1 DEV=15%
E_ABM4         N376805 0 VALUE { IF(V(FB)<1.22*0.9 | V(FB)>1.1*1.22,0,1)    }
V_V10         N64753 0 3.3
X_U54         N16800528 N16800534 d_d PARAMS:
C_CFILT3         0 N241555  1p  TC=0,0 
X_U28         N154194 N169627 INV_BASIC1V
X_U37         MAXDC MXDC_SYNC SYNCI N87095 MUX2_BASIC1V
C_CFILT5         0 N324370  4p  TC=0,0 
E_ABM5         N29782 0 VALUE { IF(V(RMP)<0.03,1,0)    }
E_U8         ZX 0 VALUE {LIMIT(V(N38710,N40278)*1E6,0,1)} _U8 N38710 N40278 1G

C_CFILT6         0 RMP_SYNC  105p  TC=0,0 
X_U15         N106678 BOOT d_d1 PARAMS:
X_U24         Q N118443 ZX V1V N90308 V1V DFFSBRB_RHPBASIC1V
R_ROEA         0 COMP R_ROEA 10MEG TC=0,0 
.model        R_ROEA RES R=1 DEV=15%
G_G4         0 RMP_SYNC N324370 0 0.369m
E_E1         N34733 0 SPV 0 0.075
G_GEA         0 N01137 VREFI FBI 1.1m
X_S11    SYNCI 0 N343790 N347980 TPS43061_TOPLEVEL_S11 
E_ABM8         N51957 0 VALUE { IF(V(ENI)>0.5,0,1)    }
X_S2    N380010 0 PGOOD 0 TPS43061_TOPLEVEL_S2 
X_U23         MXDC_SYNC N283683 INV_BASIC1V
X_S5    HSO 0 BOOT HDRV TPS43061_TOPLEVEL_S5 
X_U33         LSON N90308 INV_BASIC1V
E_DIFF3         N35569 0 VALUE {V(ISNSN,N35279)}
X_U25         RT_CLK N315819 INV_BASIC1V
R_Rvcc         VCC N106678 R_Rvcc 1 TC=0,0 
.model        R_Rvcc RES R=1 DEV=15%
E_ABM17         SYNCI_OLD 0 VALUE { IF(V(SYNC)>0.6,1,0)    }
E_E4         N16800528 0 AND_OUT 0 1
X_U10         N66939 EN d_d1 PARAMS:
X_S12    LSOFF 0 N452477 0 TPS43061_TOPLEVEL_S12 
G_GSNSM         ISNSN 0 ENI 0 70u
E_ABM62         ENI 0 VALUE { if(V(EN_OK)>0.5 & V(VIN_UVLO)>0.5, 1, 0)     }
E_E3         N347980 0 RMP_SYNC 0 1
R_R17         VIN_UVLO 0 R_R17 10k TC=0,0 
.model        R_R17 RES R=1 DEV=15%
E_ABM18         N376275 0 VALUE { IF(V(FB)>1.22*0.92 & V(FB)<1.08*1.22,0,1)   
+  }
X_S3    N51957 0 COMP 0 TPS43061_TOPLEVEL_S3 
R_R10         N89609 LSON R_R10 100k TC=0,0 
.model        R_R10 RES R=1 DEV=15%
R_R6         AGND 0 R_R6 1m TC=0,0 
.model        R_R6 RES R=1 DEV=15%
X_U29         N163042 N170009 INV_BASIC1V
X_S6    HSO 0 HDRV SW TPS43061_TOPLEVEL_S6 
G_G2         0 COMP N01594 0 1
X_U14         LSON LSOFF N257483 V1V N233062 V1V DFFSBRB_RHPBASIC1V
R_Rreset         N343790 N452477 R_Rreset 10 TC=0,0 
.model        R_Rreset RES R=1 DEV=15%
X_U31         N170009 HSOFF INV_BASIC1V
X_U57         RMPRESET SYNCI N17772 OR2_BASIC1V
X_S7    LSO 0 VCC LDRV TPS43061_TOPLEVEL_S7 
C_CFILT2         0 N89609  1p  TC=0,0 
G_GSNSP1         ISNSP 0 SPV 0 25u
R_R5         SYNC RT_CLK R_R5 1000k TC=0,0 
.model        R_R5 RES R=1 DEV=15%
R_R16         PWPD 0 R_R16 1m TC=0,0 
.model        R_R16 RES R=1 DEV=15%
X_U42         MXDC_SYNC N369594 N366597 OR2_BASIC1V
R_R9         N163042 N164374 R_R9 35k TC=0,0 
.model        R_R9 RES R=1 DEV=15%
X_U50         SS N64753 d_d PARAMS:
X_U36         CLK CLK_SYNC SYNCI N257483 MUX2_BASIC1V
R_R8         N154194 N110360 R_R8 50k TC=0,0 
.model        R_R8 RES R=1 DEV=15%
E_ABM9         N52919 0 VALUE { IF(V(ENI)>0.5,0,1)    }
X_U22         XDX N380010 0 0 N376805 N376275 DFFSBRB_RHPBASIC1V
R_R1         0 N01137 R_R1 1 TC=0,0 
.model        R_R1 RES R=1 DEV=15%
X_U53         RMP N168114250 d_d PARAMS:
C_CFILT1         0 N163042  1p  TC=0,0 
X_U21         N222430 RMPQB RMPRESET 0 SYNCI_INV N22414 DFFSBRB_RHPBASIC1V
X_S1    N17772 0 RMP 0 TPS43061_TOPLEVEL_S1 
E_ABM12         N110360 0 VALUE { IF(V(LDRV)>0.25,0,1)    }
C_CFILT         0 N154194  1p  TC=0,0 
X_S8    LSO 0 LDRV PGND TPS43061_TOPLEVEL_S8 
E_ABM15         N134304 0 VALUE { IF(V(ENI)>0.5,0.7,0)    }
E_DIFF1         N33298 0 VALUE {V(COMP,N452477)}
E_ABM7         SLP 0 VALUE { IF(V(RMP)<0.96, (0.335*V(RMP)), 0)    }
R_R18         N16800534 N16800528 R_R18 4.91 TC=0,0 
.model        R_R18 RES R=1 DEV=15%
E_E2         HDRVL 0 HDRV SW 1
X_S4    N52919 0 SS 0 TPS43061_TOPLEVEL_S4 
V_V7         N24138 0 1
X_U16         N320210 CLK_SYNC BUF_DELAY_BASIC1V PARAMS: DELAY=10N
X_U40         N309663 N247956 d_d PARAMS:
R_R13         N247956 MXDC_SYNC R_R13 75k TC=0,0 
.model        R_R13 RES R=1 DEV=15%
E_DIFF2         N34828 0 VALUE {V(ISNSP,N34733)}
X_U11         N66939 N70705 d_d1 PARAMS:
E_ABM10         EN_OK 0 VALUE { IF(V(EN)>1.2,1,0)    }
X_U48         N134304 COMP d_d PARAMS:
E_ABM2         FBI 0 VALUE { IF(V(FB)<0.1,(1.15*V(FB)-15m),V(FB))    }
X_U19         ENI LSOFF N90308 N114161 AND3_BASIC1V
E_LIMIT3         SPV 0 VALUE {LIMIT(V(N33298),0,2)}
V_V11         N70705 0 4
R_R4         N03382 RT_CLK R_R4 100 TC=0,0 
.model        R_R4 RES R=1 DEV=15%
C_CFILT7         0 N16800534  1u  TC=0,0 
X_U34         N221992 RMPQB RMPRESET NOR2_BASIC1V
X_U43         SYNCI N369594 INV_BASIC1V
X_U49         COMP N140118 d_d PARAMS:
C_CFILT4         0 N247956  0.75p  TC=0,0 
X_U32         ZX N186565 INV_BASIC1V
G_G3         0 N74211 ENI 0 3.2u
X_F1    N03473 N03382 0 RMP TPS43061_TOPLEVEL_F1 
X_S13    VIN 0 N662486 VIN_UVLO TPS43061_TOPLEVEL_S13 
E_ABM3         N03473 0 VALUE { IF(V(ENI)>0.5,0.52,0)    }
X_U45         SW HDRV d_d1 PARAMS:
X_U26         N16800593 N16800609 BUF_DELAY_BASIC1V PARAMS: DELAY=10n
X_U18         LSON N89609 LSO AND2_BASIC1V
V_V8         N35279 0 75m
E_ABM11         N106678 0 VALUE { IF(V(ENI)>0.5,5.5,0)    }
X_U55         0 N16800534 SYNCI OR2_BASIC1V
X_U46         HDRV BOOT d_d1 PARAMS:
X_U20         N186565 N118443 N114161 HSO AND3_BASIC1V
V_V12         V1V 0 1
I_I2         0 N66939 DC 1.8u  
E_ABM13         N164374 0 VALUE { IF(V(HDRVL)>0.25,0,1)    }
X_U44         PGND LDRV d_d1 PARAMS:
X_U41         N315819 N241555 MXDC_SYNC AND2_BASIC1V
V_V14         N168114250 0 1.2
X_S9    N366597 0 RMP_SYNC 0 TPS43061_TOPLEVEL_S9 
X_U52         CLK_SYNC N16800593 INV_BASIC1V
E_LIMIT1         N01594 0 VALUE {LIMIT(V(N01137),-150u,150u)}
X_U17         ENI N86008 INV_BASIC1V
E_ABM6         MAXDC 0 VALUE { IF(V(RMP)>0.95,1,0)    }
.ENDS TPS43061_TRANS
*$
```

I left out the top level sub-circuits and other included models to keep the message short but I can always post it in the comments if it is necessary.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, TI made a mistake with the model. The E_U lines should be written as

```
E_U7 PWMOK 0 VALUE {LIMIT(V(N34828,N35569)*1E6,0,1)} 
R_U7 N34828 N35569 1G
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome to the community.

Your issue looks like an unsupported syntax for defining voltage sources in LTSpice. As per the LTSpice Help, the correct syntax for defining a voltage source is:

> Syntax: Exxx n+ n- nc+ nc- gain
>
> This circuit element asserts an output voltage between the nodes n+ and n- that depends on the input voltage between nodes nc+ and nc-. This is a linearly dependent source specified solely by a constant gain.

For the model which you are referring to, the gain parameter is replaced with a behavioral expression.

Please try modifying the syntax to:

```
E_U7         PWMOK 0 N34828 N35569 VALUE {LIMIT(V(N34828,N35569)*1E6,0,1)} 
+  1G
```

and see if it helps to clear off the error. If the error is resolved, please confirm with your TI FAE if the node label assignments (n+ n- nc+ nc-) used in the TI PSpice model is intended in the same order as how we re-assigned. Once you get this confirmation too, you can close the simulation.

Comment: Please note that you may see the same issue with E_U5 and E_U8 too once the error on E_U7 is resolved

Comment: Sorry to make you have to LMGTFY. It seems that there is rarely an LTSpice question that isn't answered by LTSpice Help. I just had trouble finding the starting point. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @TheCarl Glad to be of help.
If my answer helped in any way, you could add an upvote to it.